# SearchView with rounded corners in ActionBar

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

I am working on an app needing a SearchView in the search fragment.

I obviously know how to create a classic `SearchView`, but how is it possible to customize it to get a result like this :

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use `CardView`to wrap the `SearchView`

[image]

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```